# Probability Spaces

Tags: probability-theory

Assume an infinite probability space

Comment: Please [do not use image for the essential part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: I rewrote the first part of the question with MathJax. Use that as a reference and fill out the rest.

Comment: Fixed it - sorry and thank you for the example!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** What are the mean $\ \mu_n\ $ and standard deviation $\ \sigma_n\ $ of $\ \frac{H_n}{n}\ $? By how many of those standard deviations does the quantity $\ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}\ $ exceed that mean—i.e. for what number $\ S_{n,m}\ $ is $\ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}=\mu_n+ S_{n,m}  \sigma_n\ $?  What is the relation between $\ S_{n,m}\ $ and the quantity $\ R(n,m)\ $ you've been asked to find?